# Repository pattern connection string

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, ormlite-servicestack

I am building a generic Repository for a WinForms kinda small app like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query);
    T GetByID(int id);
    void Add(T item);
    void Update(T item);
    void Delete(T item);
}
```

I know that many recommend against using the repository pattern, but in this case saves a lot of code, since all the POCO's will be very similar and use all the methods declared in the interface.

This will be implemented using ServiceStack.OrmLite.

I don't want to use `ConfigurationManager` to get the connection string. What would be a good way to achieve this? I thought about using a `BaseRepository` class to initialize a static connection string, but I am not sure how to implement this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you want to use ConfigurationManager to manage the connection string?

Comment: Usually connection string is managed by a `ConfigurationManager` and is injected into a `Session` class. A session instance is further injected into repository so when you query a database it goes like `repo -> session -> execute query`

Comment: @DavidKemp For other reasons I am not allowed to ship the App.config file.

Comment: @HMihail - I'm intrigues as to why you can't ship app.config, but there are other settings that can go in there that determine the app's behaviour

Answer (score 0):

A `BaseRepository` class woudl be an abstract class that implements the methods in `IRepostiory<T>` abstractly:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRespository<T> where T : class
{
    protected readonly string ConnectionString = "your connection string here"; /*could event be static?*/

    public abstract IEnumerable<T> GetAll();
    /*....*/
}
```

I've not used OrmLite, but it looks like you could probably implement most of the methods in the `BaseRepository` class. Any decent DI container could then use this, rather than having to have a separate repository class for each entity.

However, as the Repository pattern is typically used with the Unit of Work pattern, you might want to consider how this all communicates.

One final note: I'd warn against `GetAll` as `IEnumerable` - apart from maybe lookup tables will only ever have a small number of rows. Once you start to have any volume of data, you'll need to retrieve it in chunks - loading hundreds of thousands (or more?) records in one go will be pretty slow.

Comment: Mixing configuration and code is a bad idea. You don't want to recompile application every time configuration changes.

Comment: @oleksii - hence my question about why the OP doesn't want to use ConfigurationManager

Comment: @DavidKemp - I read the connection string at app startup, from a .ini file present on the machine. I was thinking about initializing in the BaseRepository with some Init() method at app startup, but I am not sure if this is a good approach?

Comment: @DavidKemp - regarding `GetAll`, I am aware of that, and for the entities that will hold many records, I will implement pagination or something similar in their `Repository` implementation.

Comment: @HMihail - yeah, that could work - if you're using a DI/IoC container, you could wire it all up in the setup of that.